# Should I capitalize a common noun if it precedes its name like Organization A?

Tags: capitalization

In this chart, **Organization** is capitalized. I wonder if it's just the way it's written in the chart, or I actually have to follow this style in my report.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of "title case".  You can see title case being used for all the labels on the graph, like "Machinery" and "Staff Training".  In title case, most words start with a capital letter, except for some short internal words.

It is common to use title case for things like the titles of books or the labels on a graph. And the labels "Organisation A" have been written in title case. If you were to embed the same word in a sentence, you would use "sentence case" for example "I noted that organization B spend the most money"